# Can i use a navigation drawer as a dropdown menu when i click on an item in a recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

Im using a **Navigation drawer** as a dropdown when i select an item in my recyclerview, but im not sure if im supposed to use a navigation drawer as a dropdown list.

Everything works fine except i have some problem when i swipe between fragments, the drawer doesn't close.

Just want to know if it's okay to use a drawer this way.

```
NavigationView mNavigationView2;

        mNavigationView2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.nav_view2);

        initRecyclerView();

        mNavigationView2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color1));
        mNavigationView2.setItemIconTintList(null);

        mNavigationView2.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                final Dialog dialog;
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.ic_edit:
                    //code when edit is clicked in dropdown.
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, you may want to add a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve as it's not very easy to understand it just by reading your post. Thanks.

Comment: I'm just wondering if i can use a navigation drawer https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer  as a dropdown list when i click on an item in a recyclerview

Comment: Because in the documentation it is mostly used for  app's main navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear about what you really want to achieve.
If i'm not wrong, you want to reuse the list of options (from **res/menu**) of navigation drawer in recyclerview dropdown options.
You may take a look at this:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus